# Spliting a string based on multiple characters

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0

I am trying to split a string with multiple characters. The string might sometimes contain a `-` or a `/`. What I have achieved is the hyphen but I am not able to search for the slash. Any thoughts on how to split the string based on both characters at once ? Once I split after `-` I add the value after the `-` to the `result` list as a separate index and I would like to accomplish the same for `'/'`.

So For example  the `Split` string has `Jet-blue`, the below code will add `Jet` in the `result` list with `index(0)` and `blue` with `index(1)`. In addition to splitting with `'-'` I would also like to split with `'/'`. Any suggestions ?

Code:

```
    Dim result As New List(Of String)()

    For Each str_get As String In Split

        Dim splitStr = str_get.Split("-") 

        For Each str_split As String In splitStr

            result.Add(str_split) ' Enter into result list

            ' result.TrimExcess()
        Next

        result.Remove("")

    Next
```

Comment: Please give us one or multiple strings as sample data and a desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) or [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx) overload of the [`Split` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx).

The first one takes an array of `Char`:

```
"Hello World".Split({"e"c, "o"c}) ' Notice the c!
```

The second one takes an array of `String` and [`StringSplitOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions.aspx):

```
"Hello World".Split({"el", "o"}, StringSplitOptions.None)
```